# Why can't PhantomJS/Poltergeist pull up this website correctly?

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I'm using Capybara to navigate a web page. The url look like this:

```
http://www.myapp.com/page/ABCXYZ?page=<x>
```

The page has a paginated table on it. Passing a page number to it will paginate the table appropriately.

However, when using the `poltergeist` driver, the `page` parameter is always ignored.

Using the `selenium` driver is not an option because it's a hassle to get it to run headless, it doesn't want to run more than one time (gives "connection refused" error on localhost).

This looks like an encoding issue, but I'm not sure where exactly in the stack that the issue lies.

```
class Verifier
  class << self

    include Capybara::DSL
    Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 10

    def parse_table(header)
      xpath = '//*[@id="products"]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/div[4]/div/table'
      table = find(:xpath, xpath)
      rows = []
      table.all("tr").each do |row|
        product_hash = {}
        row.all("td").each_with_index do |col,idx|
          product_hash[header[idx]] = col.text
        end
        rows << product_hash
      end
      rows
    end

    def pages
      page.find(".numberofresults").text.gsub(" Products","").split(" ").last.to_i/25
    end

    def import(item)

      visit "http://www.myapp.com/page/#{item}"

      header = parse_header
      apps = parse_vehicles(header)
      pages.times do |pagenumber|
        url = "http://www.myapp.com/page/#{item}?page=#{pagenumber+1}" # This is the problem
      end

    end
  end
```

That url in the last loop? It is processes as if the pagenumber is not present. When I change the driver to `:selenium`, this whole thing works. So it's not a Capybara issue as far as I can see.

Comment: You can start by showing some code.

Comment: isnt `page` an alias for `Capybara::Session` so you would do things like `page.find` etc. could this be causing you an issue?

Comment: ```page``` is the scope in which everything is executed anyway (```Capybara::Session``` just like you say). I could just as easily do ```find``` by itself and it works the same.

Comment: clearly the result of this guy is not giving you what you want using phantomjs:

page.find(".numberofresults").text.gsub(" Products","").split(" ").last.to_i/25

can you debug that guy using selenium then poltergeist and let us know the difference? you may need to either wait for the page to load prior to triggering the find (headless could load the page but not all the elements like a browser does) or using some other native getter for the text of the element...